# Возможно увеличить масштаб карты, когда она отображает раскрывшиеся метки кластера?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Иногда при нажатии на метку кластера карта отображает его метки прямо на границе окна (пример ниже). Подскажите, возможно ли как-то отследить подобную ситуацию, чтобы уменьшить масштаб на единицу? Или, хотя бы, в любом случае уменьшить масштаб карты на единицу после отображения меток кластера?[image: Пример того, как могут отображаться метки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите кластеризатору учёт отступов `useMapMargin`, и задайте удобные вам отступы через заданных [map.margin.Manager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.margin.Manager.html) или сразу при настройке карты.

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
        margin: [50,50,50,50],
        zoom: 9
    }),
    clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
        useMapMargin: true
    })
```

Для менеджера объектов всё делается аналогично.

```
var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    useMapMargin: true
});
```

...или: `objectManager.options.set({useMapMargin: true});`

Но вообще `useMapMargin` по-умолчанию включен, специально включать его не требуется.

[Пример на эту тему](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/margin_manager) в песочнице Яндекса есть.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хочу точнить: я добавляю метки через ObjectManager, не создавая отдельно кластеризатор. В этом случае получится включить учёт отступов так: objectManagerMy.clusters.options.set({ useMapMargin: true }) ?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.